# What is the minimum value of $|x^TAx|$ non Hermitian matrix ? ($||x||_2 = 1$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a non Hermitian complex matrix $A$ $\in \mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$.
I have real vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with euclidean norm $||x||_2=1$.
What is the minimum values obtainable for $|x^TAx|$ over all possible $x$ ?

Comment: Is it positive definite by any chance?

Comment: If $x$ is complex and the rank of $A$ is at least $2$, the answer will be zero. For real $x$, you are essentially minimising $\sqrt{|x^TS(X)x|^2+|x^TS(Y)x|^2}$, where $S(X)$ and $S(Y)$ are the symmetric parts of the real and imaginary parts of $A$. I think the minimum can only be found numerically.